# Why one needs to call UseRewriter() before defining routes in UseMvc()?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, url-rewriting, routes, startup

I created simple rewriter and called `app.UseRewriter` after defining routes:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {...});
app.UserRewriter(new RequestCatcher());
```

When I use browser and go to:

- `http:\\localhost:5050\test` ApplyRule method is never executed
- `http:\\localhost:5050\test` only requests for files like `css`,`json`,`js` are caught and processed in the `ApplyRule` method

  ```
   public class RequestCatcher : IRule
   {
      public RequestCatcher()
      {
      }
      public void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
      {
          var request = context.HttpContext.Request;

          if (request.Path.Value.EndsWith("/", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
          {
          }
      }
  }
  ```

Only when I move `app.UseRewriter(rewriteOptions);` call before defining routes all requests are processed in `ApplyRule` method. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Middlewares are executed in the order they are registered. If you put it after `UseMvc` then only if Mvc did handle it, it would be rewritten. But at that point, its already too late since the action has been handled.

See the [Middlewares](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) documentation.

> The order that middleware components are added in the Startup.Configure method defines the order in which the middleware components are invoked on requests and the reverse order for the response. The order is critical for security, performance, and functionality.